# Why can't call chrome.runtime.sendMessage in chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

when I write below code and run it I got error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

worker.js:

```
async function createOffscreen() {
  if (await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()) return;
  await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: "offscreen.html",
    reasons: ["AUDIO_PLAYBACK"],
    justification: "testing",
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (msg) => {
  switch (msg.type) {
    case "play":
      await createOffscreen();
      await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: "play",
        play: msg.play,
        offscreen: true,
      });
      break;
    case "pause":
      await createOffscreen();
      await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "pause", offscreen: true });
      break;
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "pause", offscreen: true });
    }
    
)
```

I want to send message when the url changed, does there have any other methods to do it?

Comment: The simplest solution in this case might be to simply suppress the error by adding `()=>chrome.runtime.lastError` callback or `.catch(()=>{})` to sendMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thanks for the correction.  OP's code appears to expect the message.  And if messages aren't delivered to the sender then that explains the error message, i.e., there is nothing listening for the message.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be an issue where your onUpdated listener is trying to send a message, but it has nowhere to send that message to. The solution would depend on what you're trying to do:

- If you're trying to send the pause message to the offscreen document, you'll want to make sure to create it first. Your onUpdated doesn't currently have any logic for this.
- If you're trying to communicate between two parts of your background service worker, maybe consider events or just directly calling functions instead?